# Incorrect Mock test, shows no errors but its not given accurate result ,why?

Tags: spring

```
 This is the controller class

@RequestMapping(value="/remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String remove(
            @ModelAttribute("id") String id, Model model
    ) {
        bookService.removeOne(Long.parseLong(id.substring(8)));
        List<Book> bookList = bookService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("bookList", bookList);

        return "redirect:/book/bookList";
    }
```

This is the controller test

```
    @Test
    public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
        securityService.autologin("admin", "admin");
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(2L);
        book.setTitle("brekit");
        bookService.findOne(2L);
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/remove/2")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        ).andDo(print())
                .andReturn();
    }
```

### Results in no error but when I change the value on the URL it still shows correct test, its suppose to remove the said id, any suggestion guys ?

I have tried also this

```
 @Test
    public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
        securityService.autologin("admin", "admin");
        List<Book> bookList = bookService.findAll();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(2L);
        book.setTitle("brekit");
        bookService.findOne(2L);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/remove/2")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andReturn();

        String controllerResult = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(null, controllerResult);
    }
```

And I get the same error -assertion error? I'm new at this any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking the return value (aka: assertXXX) or the http code. Try something similar:

```
   MvcResult result = mockMvc
      .perform(post("/remove/2")
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andReturn();
```

Please note **andExpect(status().isOk())**. Everything that is different from 200 will throw an error.

Then you can check the result decoding the result into your business object:

```
String controllerResult = result.getResponse().getContentAsString()
assertEquals(expected, controllerResult)
```